# Limit of exec() command in PHP?

Tags: php, exec

I am using exec command in PHP to execute C++ code where record_generate.cpp is code which generate output(100 to millions of records) based on hard coded parameters.

```
exec('./record_generater 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);
```

When number of output lines are limited to few thousand it gives output but when it reaches to 100,000s to million it seems to be crashed. How can i avoid such pblms?

Comment: It crashes when you print a million lines to the browser, how strange ?

Comment: Not in printing but during execution as i can print those records using command line but using browser there is pblm (no output).

Answer (score 1):

The *first* thing you should do is to see if running the C++ program from a shell causes a similar problem.

If so, it's a problem with the C++ code itself and nothing to do with PHP `exec`.

If it works okay standalone, then it's probably going to be related to storing millions of records into the `$output` variable.

While a string in PHP can be pretty big (2G from memory), there's a limited *total* space available to scripts, specified by `memory_limit_ in the`php.ini` file.

Even at 128M (8M prior to 5.2), this may not be enough to hold millions of lines.

You could try increasing that variable to something larger and see if it helps.

However, you will probably still be better off finding a *different* way to get the information from your C++ executable into your PHP code, such as writing it to a file/database and processing it in PHP a bit at a time, rather than trying to store the lot in memory at once.

In any case, given that it's not really a good user experience to have to look through millions of rows anyway, it might be worthwhile examining what you really *need* from this data. For example, it may be possible to aggregate or partition it in some manner before outputting.

Any advice we give on that front will need substantially more information than we currently have.

Comment: It was working well if i run standalone C++ code. I works also well when i  ran exe and piped out the results and read from the file. But it makes this makes it slower.

Comment: @user15662: well, do you want it slow and reliable, or fast and crashing? I know which I'd prefer :-) But, if you want it fast and reliable, you'll need to examine other approaches. To advise on that, we'll need _way_ more information, see the update.